# Camera calibration with OpenCV-python for autonomous car doesn't work well

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

### Problems

#### doesn't work well

When I use my code with my Image, it doesn't work well.

I only edited 'wc' and 'hc' from [OpenCV DOC](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)
import glob

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

wc = 7
hc = 4

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((wc * hc, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:hc, 0:wc].T.reshape(-1, 2)
# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.
images = glob. Glob('1.jpg')
for fname in images:
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (hc, wc), None)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    print(ret, wc, hc)

    if True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (20, 20), (-1, -1),
                                   criteria)  # image, corners, winSize, zeroZone, criteria
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        # Draw and display the corners
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (hc, wc), corners2, ret)
        cv.imwrite('ChessboardCorners.png', img)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

        img = cv.imread('1.jpg')
        print(img.shape[:2])
        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

        # undistort
        dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
        # crop the image
        x, y, w, h = roi
        dst = dst[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cv.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        mean_error = 0
        for i in range(len(objpoints)):
            imgpoints2, _ = cv.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
            error = cv.norm(imgpoints[i], imgpoints2, cv.NORM_L2) / len(imgpoints2)
            mean_error += error
        print("total error: {}".format(mean_error / len(objpoints)))
        print("\n\n", fname, "claer")

        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        exit(0)
```

[original image - not well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeklp.png)

[ChessboardCorners - (I'm not sure that this is not well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUfmW.png)

[calibresult image - not well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNm9z.png)

#### works well with other images

But, when I use my code with the Image which was in the example in OpenCV DOC, it works well.

```
import glob

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

wc = 6
hc = 7

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((wc * hc, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:hc, 0:wc].T.reshape(-1, 2)
# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.
images = glob. Glob('img.png')
for fname in images:
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (hc, wc), None)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    print(ret, wc, hc)

    if True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (20, 20), (-1, -1),
                                   criteria)  # image, corners, winSize, zeroZone, criteria
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        # Draw and display the corners
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (hc, wc), corners2, ret)
        cv.imwrite('ChessboardCorners.png', img)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

        img = cv.imread('img.png')
        print(img.shape[:2])
        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

        # undistort
        dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
        # crop the image
        x, y, w, h = roi
        dst = dst[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cv.imwrite('calibresult.png', dst)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        mean_error = 0
        for i in range(len(objpoints)):
            imgpoints2, _ = cv.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
            error = cv.norm(imgpoints[i], imgpoints2, cv.NORM_L2) / len(imgpoints2)
            mean_error += error
        print("total error: {}".format(mean_error / len(objpoints)))
        print("\n\n", fname, "claer")

        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        exit(0)
```

I removed the images because "Your question appears to be spam."
Please see the images on OpenCV DOC

Please, give me the solution to this problem.
Do I need to modify the parameters, or what should I do?
Is my chessboard wrong?

---

### Below is what I have tried.

#### First, I tried to find correct numbers of 'wc' and 'hc'

I used this code to find.

```
import glob

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

for i in range(3, 50):
    for j in range(i + 1, 50): # I used this code becuase I found that the order of the variables does not matter last time.
        wc = i
        hc = j

        # termination criteria
        criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
        # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
        objp = np.zeros((wc * hc, 3), np.float32)
        objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:hc, 0:wc].T.reshape(-1, 2)
        # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
        objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
        imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.
        images = glob.glob('1.jpg')
        for fname in images:
            img = cv.imread(fname)
            gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            # Find the chess board corners
            ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (hc, wc), None)
            # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)

            print(ret, wc, hc)
```

And the result here:

```
False 3 4
False 3 5
False 3 6
···
False 4 5
False 4 6
**True 4 7**
False 4 8
False 4 9
···
False 47 48
False 47 49
False 48 49

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### I also found that the Image which was in the example in OpenCV DOC has another 'wc' and 'hc', (4, 4).

And result here:

[ChessboardCorners by (4, 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbkzm.png)

[calibresult by (4, 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MIrj.png)

So, I'm expecting that the 'wc'and 'hc' of my Image (4, 7) might be small.
Should I increase the max and do a brute-force search again?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you are only using a single input image for calibration.  If that's true, try increasing to at least 5 images (more would be better) and see if that helps.  The images should be at different angles and distances.

I notice that your lens has significant distortion.  A few suggestions for getting that to work well:

1. Use the rational model for distortion - the basic kappa 1, kappa 2 model won't do well.
2. Your data set will need to include image points from all parts of the image, including near the edges and corners of the image.  This can be difficult/impossible to achieve using the normal chessboard pattern (because the entire pattern must be visible in the image) - I suggest using the ChAruco calibration pattern/functions. This uses a modified chessboard pattern that includes Aruco markers embedded in the white squares, which allows for partial patterns to be used.

Note that the wc and hc parameters you are searching for are used to describe the chessboard pattern width and height.  This should be known to you ahead of time and you shouldn't need to search for it.